# connect remotely to couchbase server using python timeout exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, couchbase

I have bought a couchbase host server on Amazon server,

When I type this url

```
http://ec2-54-186-83-95.bla.bla.bla.com:8091/index.html
```

I got the page to enter the username and password,

Now I am trying to insert documents to that server remotely using python.

I tried this:

```
connection = Couchbase.connect(host='http://ec2-54-186-83-95.bla.bla.bla.com:8091/index.html', bucket='data')
```

That statement didn't give me any exception, so I tried to insert the data like this:

```
connection.set('key', value')
```

I got this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\couchbase\connection.py", line 331, in set
    persist_to, replicate_to)
_TimeoutError_0x17 (generated, catch TimeoutError): <Key=u'key', RC=0x17[Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout], Operational Error, Results=1, C Source=(src\multiresult.c,282)>
```

why is that happening please? should I use a different URL ?

#### Note:

I can successfully add document to my local couchbase server like this:

```
connection = Couchbase.connect(bucket='bucketName', password='bucketPassword')
```

if you want any other information please tell me.

**python 2.7, 32 bit on Windows 64 bit
Couchbase server 2.5.1**

#### Update

I belive that I should do soemthing with username and password because when I access that link from browser I got the page where I should insert my username and passord but I didn't specify that in the connection statemnt in python and when I did, I got the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the [Couchbase Python SDK Getting Started Guide](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/python/getting-started), simply use the hostname(s) of your cluster nodes - i.e. in your example:

```
connection = Couchbase.connect(host='ec2-54-186-83-95.bla.bla.bla.com',
                               bucket='data')
```

Comment: I tried your solution but then I tried this: `connection.set('key', 'value')` and I got this exception `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\couchbase\connection.py", line 331, in set
    persist_to, replicate_to)
_ConnectError_0x18 (generated, catch ConnectError): <Key=u'key', RC=0x18[Error while establishing TCP connection], Operational Error, Results=1, C Source=(src\multiresult.c,286)>
>>> `

Comment: I know that the guide didn't use password, but it is logical to use it ,otherwise it doesn't make any sence if I can access the secured bucket without correct credentials

Comment: Have you checked that there isn't a firewall or similar in the way between your client and remote machine? See http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-install/#network-ports - specifically check the "Node to Client" ports

Comment: what do you mean by check? should I check the ports or what please?

Comment: I want to tell you that my firewal is off and I have the problem so it is not from ports right?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli try telnet'ing from the client to the server on the REST API port (default 8091) and data port (default 11210), and see if a connection is established.

Comment: how can I do that please? if doing that needs a lot of typing, give me a link and I will learn myself

Comment: I alreay did a telnet and both ports 8091 and 11210 available